# Is there a log for SVN/TortoiseSVN's output when you commit something?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When I perform a commit in SVN w Tortoise it displays a message box for me to enter my log message. I then click 'ok' and away it goes to perform the actual commit. The window to enter the log message disappears and a new one is spawned showing which files are being committed. Is this output saved anywhere? I had a window open which had some red (bad) output go by. I accidentally closed the window without examining this output. Is there a way I can review that data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

```
Settings dialog->Saved Data
```

There you can see a button named `Show` in the group box `Action log`.
If you click that button, the action log file is opened in the default editor.

You can also configure how big (how many lines) that action log files can get before it gets truncated.